# Extracting Data from Google sheet whose name is in another cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have written a script to get all the names of worksheets currently present in my Google Sheet. Now I want to extract the first cell (A1) from one of the sheet names that I am fetching.

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Try `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(sheetName + '!A1').getValue()`.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).